# How do I redirect www to non-www in Route53?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, amazon-route53

I host my site at `domain.com`.

My DNS entries in Route53 are as follows:

```
domain.com      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      300
domain.com      NS      stuff.awsdns-47.org  172800
domain.com      SOA     stuff.awsdns-47.org  900
```

I would like to redirect traffic from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`, as currently this just returns a 404. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11370393/319618) suggested a `PTR` record, and I added that:

```
www.domain.com  PTR     domain.com           300
```

but it didn't work. What should I be doing?

Comment: If you actually want to send a HTTP redirect, you can't do it inside DNS.  If you don't care about the URL in the address bar changing, use a CNAME as pauska suggests.  If you do care, you will need a web server of some sort to send the 301.  Some DNS providers have this as a service, but I don't believe Route53 does this.

Comment: @cjc I don't care about the URL in the address bar.

Comment: For other readers using Cloudflare, this worked for me: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirecting-www-to-non-www/2949/28

Answer (score 29, accepted):

PTR is for setting up reverse IP lookups, and it's not something you should care about. Remove it.

What you need is a CNAME for www:

```
www.domain.com  CNAME  domain.com 300
```

Comment: This is not a redirect. In case, you have to define callback URL in some sort of third party service, above solution will not work. For example oAuth(Facebook, Twitter) Authentication.

Comment: nope, not working

Comment: CNAME would mean you have duplicate content on www and Apex, which isn't optimal for Google/SEO and gets a penalized (in SEO terms, for duplicate content).

Comment: @MathiasConradt ..what would you recommend then.

Comment: @user1388835 Doing a real redirect, as mentioned in the first comment of the original question, or first comment on here as well.

Answer (score 19):

You can also set a ALIAS for WWW to A record of domain.com:

```
www.domain.com A ALIAS domain.com 300
```

so your final DNS entries would be as follows:

```
domain.com          A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      300
domain.com          NS      stuff.awsdns-47.org  172800
domain.com          SOA     stuff.awsdns-47.org  900
www.domain.com      A       ALIAS domain.com (Hosted Zone ID)
```

Comment: I have done this however still it is not working. Anything else that may be required to be done?

Comment: After adding the alias, I needed to delete the browser cache to get this to work.

Comment: And it depends on the previous TTL of your DNS.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get this set up by leveraging an additional S3 bucket.

I want my website to be accessible at the non-www `example.com`. In my case, `example.com` is set up with a route 53 hosted zone, a s3 bucket, and a cloudfront distribution with a custom ssl cert.

I want `www.example.com` to redirect to `example.com`. To do so, I set up a new s3 bucket for `www.example.com`. I set it to [public](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html) and set up static website hosting to redirect all requests. The target bucket or domain is `example.com`. Since I have the ssl cert configured on `example.com`, I set the protocol to https.

[image]

In route 53, within the mydomain.com hosted zone, I created a new A record for `www.example.com` with an Alias that pointed to the new www s3 bucket website.

Now all requests to `www.example.com` redirect to `https://example.com`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This solution is ok for HTTP but is not working for HTTPS requests. You need to involve CloudFront to serve HTTPS. See https://serverfault.com/a/942537/7005

Comment: indeed with this method you can only redirect TO https but not FROM https, you need to do the extra step via cloudfront as in the comment linked above

Answer (score 3):

After you have a CNAME for both example.com  and www.example.com this nginx config will redirect traffic from http to https as well as all www.example.com to example.com

```
server { 

    listen  80 ;

    server_name  example.com, www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {  #  redirect www to normal domain

    listen       443  ssl ;

    server_name www.example.com;

    include /etc/nginx/myprojname/include/ssl;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen  443 ssl ;

    include /etc/nginx/myprojname/include/ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/nginx_common_location_443;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/myprojname/include/custom_server_include;
}
```

where my actual server is up and listening on port 3000 ... this also terminates my TLS however just remove mention of ssl ... tucked away in those included files are my nginx settings to harden the box

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, it's not possible with standard DNS.

Here's the solution I used:

- Setup S3 with static website redirect to your non-www domain
- Create a Cloudfront distibution to your S3 (using the S3 domain, not the one suggested in autocomplete by AWS)
- Add a Route 53 A Record alias to the CloudFront distribution

Comment: @Thomas see edited answer.

Comment: with "not the autocomplete" what is meant is that you need to copy the static website url and paste it into the origin dialogue of cloudfront. E.g.  www.example.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

After meddle up with lots of online tutorials, I found it was very easy without the need for any service other than Route53.

This is the example configuration for the domain with **www**,

[image]

This is an example configuration for the same domain **without www**,

[image]

So basically you have to copy the same configuration including the IP address again from **www.domain.com** to **domain.com**.

And that's it wait for some time to get your domain changes to propagate and you'll be able to see your website loading both in the domain with and without www.

Comment: This is not what the OP asks for, the desire is a "redirect", which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are serving the site.
The easest way is probably serve through cloudfront. That way you would simpley create the cloudfront distribution and add both the www and non-www domain as alias'. Cloudfront will take care of both.

Comment: how do you "add both www and non-www domains as alias" in cloud front? that's the question